# installing tomcat and setting environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am new to tomcat server. According to the guide offered on the internet found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/installation.html),

> I have to set an environment variable named: **CATALINA_HOME**

1) I tried to set that variable in RUNNING.txt file which is already created inside tomcat directory 
   by default. My question is, **how to set that variable correctly to have tomcat server working?**

2) As mentioned [here](http://www.apekshit.com/t/56/Writing-JSP-in-Eclipse), I should be able to create a new dynamic web page from [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), but when I make a new eclipse project, I found that the dynamic web project is not listed as mentioned in the link. Please let me know how to create a new dynamic web project from eclipse.

*Note: 1) I have tomcat server installed.
          2) eclipse could not specify my apache server. see the image below. *
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you have to go with answer of @Vimal Bera.
2. if you still don't find the option then Make sure that you have downloaded `Eclipse IDE  for Java EE Developers`.i think you have downloaded `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers`. 
   Download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
3. If you see the option then first create a Tomcat server instance by `File->New->Server->Expand Apache node and point out to your version->next->Browse to your Tomcat installation directory and click on Finish button`.
4. At the time of creation of New Dynamic web project please be insure that you have selected appropriate version of Tomcat in Target Runtime field.

[image]

Comment: I tried what did you suggest, but as seen in the image posted above, the eclipse could not specify my apache version. can you tell me how to solve this

Comment: just go to one more folder deep where you will find some other folders like bin conf etc. See the image in answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to file --> New --> Other. In that windows, there is an option like `Show all wizards`. Check that box and then try to find `Dynamic web project` under `Web` menu.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i think i need to download eclipse java EE